# Why $\left\lceil{ \frac{n}{1 +\Delta (G)}}\right\rceil \ge \gamma (G)$?

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

a dominating set for a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a subset $D$ of $V$ such that every vertex not in$ D$ is adjacent to at least one member of $D$. The domination number $γ(G)$ is the number of vertices in a smallest dominating set for $G$.

Why $\left\lceil{ \frac{n}{1 +\Delta (G)}}\right\rceil \ge \gamma (G)$?

Comment: Don't you mean $\gamma(G) \ge \ldots$?

Comment: why $\left\lceil{ \frac{n}{1 +\Delta (G)}}\right\rceil \ge \gamma (G)$?

Comment: But that's completely false.  Take $K_{100}$ plus 1000 disjoint vertices.  Then the LHS is $10$ but $\gamma(G)$ is $1001$.

Comment: Should be $\gamma(G) \ge $.

Answer (score 1):

Each vertex $v$ in a dominating set covers $1+d(v)$ vertices (itself and its $d(v)$ neigbbors).  Also, $d(v) \le \Delta$ for each vertex $v$.  Hence, each vertex in a dominating set covers at most $1+\Delta$ vertices.  Since a dominating set covers all vertices of the graph, a dominating set must have at least $|V| / (1+\Delta)$ vertices.